# Some pictures not displaying on iphone layout

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

The site has a problem on showing pictures in an iphone device, replicated this issue with the browser by minimizing it horizontally.
[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xhsjxu44h865uon/mobile%20screen%20problem.png) is the link showing the problem.
My manual fix is that i zoom out the browser(ctrl+-), [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d0r4mtegbfxgsy6/mobile%20screen%20fix.png) a link for the demo.

Is there anyway that this can be tackled with html, css or javascript/jquery.
I already have a responsive tag for the pages:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This is the html for the image div:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 fabric-box">
    <a href="customize/fabric/<?php echo $x['hash'];?>/<?php echo $_SESSION['customize_mode'];?>">
    <div class="image-holder fabric-image-holder">
        <img data-src="<?php echo ap($x['thumb']);?>" class="lazy img-responsive" src="<?php echo $conf->bg;?>"></img>
    </div></a>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <h5 class="fabric-name pull-left"><a href="customize/option_item/<?php echo $x['id'];?>"><?php echo $x['name']?></a></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <h4 data-option-group="<?php echo $x['option_group_hash'];?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="<?php echo $data_original_title;?>" id="wishlist-<?php echo $x['id']?>" class="wishlist-button pull-right">
                <span class="glyphicon <?php echo $glyphicon;?>"></span>
            </h4>
            <a href="customize/option_item/<?php echo $x['id'];?>" class="btn btn-declothe-gray btn-xs">Details</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Click [here](http://sgwebco.com/dc/customize/fabrics) for the link of the page

Comment: Give fiddle or your website link instead giving png

Comment: added link - http://sgwebco.com/dc/customize/fabrics

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues in your HTML code so it's possible that one of those things is preventing the iPhone to display the page correctly.
For example your  tags should be like this:

```
<img data-src="https://d1r2cy10vhc364.cloudfront.net/1398340678_midnight-b_RGjA.jpg" 
class="lazy img-responsive" />
```

and not like this:

```
<img data-src="https://d1r2cy10vhc364.cloudfront.net/1398340678_midnight-b_RGjA.jpg" 
class="lazy img-responsive" src=""></img>
```

(in other words no closing  tag, instead add a slash before the last ">", as by html conventions)

Also I see an improperly nested  tag.

You have this:

```
                        <a href="customize/fabric/dItjZRcTuC/">
                        <div class="image-holder fabric-image-holder">
                            <img data-src="https://d1r2cy10vhc364.cloudfront.net/1398339227_midnight-b_rMUJ.jpg" class="lazy img-responsive" src=""></img>


                        </div></a>
```

but it should be:

```
<div class="image-holder fabric-image-holder">
  <a href="customize/fabric/dItjZRcTuC/">
     <img data-src="https://d1r2cy10vhc364.cloudfront.net/1398339227_midnight-b_rMUJ.jpg" class="lazy img-responsive" />
  </div>
</a>
```

These kind of syntax errors can sometimes create issues that don't show on some browsers but show on others. Depends on standard compliancy. You can try validating your syntax here: http://validator.w3.org/